Internet connectivity: Windows 11 host, Ubuntu 22.04 VMware client, two identically configured computers behave differently
I have two Windows 11 machines, each with VMware Workstation 17 Player and each with a virtual Ubuntu 22.04 client OS loaded and running. I can ssh from one virtual client to the other and transfer files. One of the clients can see the internet, i.e., use nslookup, surf the web, ssh to supercomputing resources, etc. The other cannot.
Both VMware network interfaces are set to connect at power on, bridges, and replicate physical network connection state. The IP addresses for both machines are on the same subdomain. Here they are: 10.0.0.213 and 10.0.0.11. The two Windows host machines are 10.0.0.31 and 10.0.0.190.
netstat -nr yields the identical routing information on both Ubuntu virtual machines:
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags   MSS Window  irtt Iface
0.0.0.0         10.0.0.1        0.0.0.0         UG        0 0          0 ens33
10.0.0.0        0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U         0 0          0 ens33
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U         0 0          0 ens33

ipconfig on the two Windows hosts yields the following. On the one that allows me to reach the internet from the virtual Ubuntu client, I see:
VMware Network Adapter VMnet1:  192.168.11.1
VMware Network Adapter VMnet8:  192.168.48.1

On the one that doesn't work, I see:
VMware Network Adapter VMnet1: 192.168.152.1
VMware Network Adapter VMnet8:  192.168.115.1

Both Windows machines connect to the internet fine.
I do not thoroughly understand the network stuff and would appreciate any direction you can provide.

try troubleshooting with traceroute to see where the packets stop

Thank you for your editorial suggestions and for the suggestion to check traceroute. traceroute showed that the network connectivity was actually working but that no naming services were available. I entered the DNS servers by hand using the Ubuntu "Network Settings" GUI and it is now fixed. nslookup, ssh, rsync, and web browsing now work. Thank you all.
